# rabbitmq-message-deduplication pluggin

Tags: rabbitmq

I try to use rabbit's plugin: [rabbitmq-message-deduplication](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication).
One of mandatory parameters is `x-cache-size`, but I don't understand what unit of this value.

Can someone explain it?

Thank you.

Comment: When deduplicating at the exchange, the plugin relies on an internal cache to store the messages which have been routed through it. As Luke Bakken said, the `x-cache-size` controls the number of entries within the cache. The bigger the cache, the more entries you can deduplicate at the cost of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x-cache-size` is the maximum limit of the number of entries in the cache. It is used [here](https://github.com/noxdafox/rabbitmq-message-deduplication/blob/9b66814e173ff02486f2ac876b779c9163426fe1/lib/cache.ex#L197-L200) and corresponds to the `mnesia` table property [`size`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#table_info-2).

If you set `x-cache-size` to `100`, then there will never be more than `100` items cached.